# Trace in a thermal state

Tags: photons, thermal-radiation, quantum-optics

A thermal state is defined as $\rho_T = \frac{e^{-\beta \hat{H}}}{Tr[e^{-\beta \hat{H}}]}$. For the single mode Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \hbar \omega \hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$. How is the trace in the denominator of $\rho_T$ computed?  Which basis is convenent to work with? Since $\hat{a}$ has infinite dimensional respresentation, does the trace make sence here?

Answer (score 1):

For a single-mode thermal state, it's most convenient to perform the trace in the number basis $a^\dagger a\lvert n\rangle = n\lvert n \rangle$ (although a coherent-state basis calculation is pretty neat, too). You might wish to remind yourself of the geometric sum identity ($a<1$)
$$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a^n = \frac{1}{1-a}.$$
Note that, since here $a = {\rm e}^{-\hbar \beta \omega}<1,$ there is no issue with tracing over an infinite-dimensional basis of states because the sum converges.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Mitchison. Could you suggest some problem book on Quantum Optics? I am new to the field and want to start with some comprehensible stuff.

Comment: I was fortunate enough to have a good undergraduate course in quantum optics and so I can't really tell you about textbook exercises, but I have used Scully & Zubairy's book in the past and found its presentation quite pedagogical.